# Unable to launch certain applications in MAC

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a single answer to satisfy my issue.  I have a few applications on Mac (10.9.2) that no longer open via their icons.  I can open a Terminal window and type 'open /Applications/[app_name]' and they work fine but attempting to open via the LaunchPad fails.  IntelliJ is the most recent application that is causing me headaches.  When I click on the icon I receive the following error in the system log:

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[306] (com.jetbrains.intellij.ce.76944[5866]): Exited with code: 1
```

I have checked my UID and I am 503 so I should be able to open it.  This only happens with certain applications though.  Network Connect (Juniper Networks) is another one that has recently started to cause issues:

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[306] (net.juniper.NetworkConnect.30128[6000]): Exited with code: 1
```

Any help in understanding what is going on would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You seriously down voted it because it had a tag that you didn't feel applied despite the problem residing with the LaunchPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love how I keep being the one to answer my own question but anyways, I found the solution.  I ended up reverting the LaunchPad back to its default settings by using the following command:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db; killall Dock
```

Once the dock database was rebuilt everything worked as expected.  Hopefully this helps other out there who have this problem.

Comment: I have this problem with intellij, but the fix didn't work for me.